# Use tensorflow lite with Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Environment :

- OS : Win10 64bits
- Qt: 5.12.3
- NDK: r18b
- JDK: jdk1.8.0_201

I would like to use the tensorflow-lite with Qt5, but there are lots of issues when I try to import the java classes. But how could I download the tensorflow-lite-gpu, tensorflow-lite-cpu and tensorflow-lite-support?

The android studio make this work with 3 lines in the build.gradle, I try to add the 3 lines into the build.gradle too.

```
dependencies {
    // Build off of nightly TensorFlow Lite
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly'    
}
```

Error messages

At [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/us0j5NZc) since it is long

I can build [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android) by android studio without any issues, how could I use the java api of tensorflow with Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, only need to add a few lines into the build.gradle(from QtCreator, projects(alt+x)->other files->build.gradle)

1. Put following lines in the "android" block of build.gradle

   ```
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
      targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    aaptOptions {
      noCompress "tflite"
    }
   ```
2. Change dependencies block(not the one in the buildscript) of the build.gradle to

   ```
   dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

      // Build off of nightly TensorFlow Lite
      implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
      implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
      implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly' 
   }
   ```

This should do the job, the complete build.gradle looks like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

    // Build off of nightly TensorFlow Lite
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly'
    // Use local TensorFlow library
    // implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-local:0.0.0'
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```